# Skip Where clause dynamically

Tags: sql, database, oracle, dynamic, where-clause

Is it possible to skip where clause dynamically?

I am trying this to achieve the same.

```
select count(*)
      into user_count
from mstuser a
where ((gender_compare is not null or gender_compare != '') 
   and upper(a.gender)=upper(gender_compare)) 
   and (age_compare_group is not null or age_compare_group != '') 
   and (MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate, a.dob) / 12 
        between substr(age_compare_group, 0, INSTR(age_compare_group, '-') - 1) 
            and substr(age_compare_group, INSTR(age_compare_group, '-') + 1)))
```

But it seems it is not working.

What i want is :

It should give all the results if both of the values `gender_compare` and `age_compare_group` is null.
If any of them not null then it should display result on the basis of where part of the query.

Let me know if i can do some thing else for the same.

Comment: You can Use Dynamic SQL

Answer (score 4):

Looks like what you have to do is to split your condition into two groups

```
WHERE (gender_compare IS NULL OR gender_compare = '')
      OR (<the rest of condition>)
```

If `genter_compare IS NULL` evaluates to `TRUE`, the whole condition will be `TRUE`, so `WHERE` clause will be equivalent to `WHERE TRUE`, which is equivalent to no `WHERE` statement at all.

Otherwise, second condition will be effective.

Comment: `gender_compare = ''` is redundant as it will always be `FALSE`. This is because oracle stores an empty string as a `NULL` value and testing a `NULL` for equality to anything else always returns `FALSE`.

Comment: ah, there is an 'oracle' in tags!

Answer (score 2):

I've wrapped the SQL into a function to make it easier to show some tests:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4c679/5)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE mstuser ( id, gender, dob ) AS
          SELECT 1, 'M', SYSDATE - INTERVAL '1' YEAR FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'M', SYSDATE - INTERVAL '2' YEAR FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'M', SYSDATE - INTERVAL '3' YEAR FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'F', SYSDATE - INTERVAL '1' YEAR FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 5, 'F', SYSDATE - INTERVAL '2' YEAR FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 6, 'F', SYSDATE - INTERVAL '3' YEAR FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 7, 'F', SYSDATE - INTERVAL '4' YEAR FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 8, 'F', SYSDATE - INTERVAL '5' YEAR FROM DUAL
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION count_by_compare (
  gender_compare    mstuser.gender%TYPE,
  age_compare_group VARCHAR2
) RETURN NUMBER
AS
  user_count NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(1)
  INTO   user_count
  FROM   mstuser a
  WHERE  (   gender_compare IS NULL
          OR UPPER( a.gender ) = UPPER(gender_compare)
         ) 
  AND    (   age_compare_group IS NULL
          OR MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate, a.dob) / 12 
             BETWEEN TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR(age_compare_group, 1, INSTR(age_compare_group, '-') - 1) )
                 AND TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR(age_compare_group, INSTR(age_compare_group, '-') + 1) )
         );
  return user_count;
END;
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH Tests AS (
            SELECT 'M' AS gender, '0-1' AS age FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL SELECT 'F', '0-6' FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL SELECT 'F', '0-1' FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL SELECT 'M', '0-6' FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL SELECT NULL, '0-2' FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL SELECT 'M', NULL FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL SELECT 'F', NULL FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL SELECT NULL, NULL FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL SELECT '', '' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT gender,
       age,
       SUBSTR(age, 1, INSTR(age, '-') - 1),
       SUBSTR(age, INSTR(age, '-') + 1),
       count_by_compare( gender, age )
FROM   Tests
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4c679/5/0)**:

```
| GENDER |    AGE | SUBSTR(AGE,1,INSTR(AGE,'-')-1) | SUBSTR(AGE,INSTR(AGE,'-')+1) | COUNT_BY_COMPARE(GENDER,AGE) |
|--------|--------|--------------------------------|------------------------------|------------------------------|
|      M |    0-1 |                              0 |                            1 |                            1 |
|      F |    0-6 |                              0 |                            6 |                            5 |
|      F |    0-1 |                              0 |                            1 |                            1 |
|      M |    0-6 |                              0 |                            6 |                            3 |
| (null) |    0-2 |                              0 |                            2 |                            4 |
|      M | (null) |                         (null) |                       (null) |                            3 |
|      F | (null) |                         (null) |                       (null) |                            5 |
| (null) | (null) |                         (null) |                       (null) |                            8 |
| (null) | (null) |                         (null) |                       (null) |                            8 |
```

Also, you don't need to test for `!= ''` as oracle represents an empty string as a `NULL` - see the final test above or the empty string comparisons below:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN '' = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS equal,
       CASE WHEN '' != '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS not_equal,
       CASE WHEN '' IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS is_null,
       CASE WHEN '' IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS is_not_null
FROM DUAL
```

Gives the result:

```
| EQUAL | NOT_EQUAL | IS_NULL | IS_NOT_NULL |
|-------|-----------|---------|-------------|
|     0 |         0 |       1 |           0 |
```

Comment: Thanks for the such a good answer with good and clean explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You would normally compare with gender_compare when gender_compare is not null and compare with age_compare_group when age_compare_group is not null. You can also state it like this: "either gender_compare is null or I compare with it" and "either age_compare_group is null or I compare with it". And this is how you would write the select statement accordingly:

```
select count(*)
  into user_count
from mstuser a
where 
( 
  gender_compare is null 
 or 
  upper(a.gender) = upper(gender_compare)
) -- compare gender if given
and
( 
  age_compare_group is null 
 or 
  months_between(sysdate, a.dob) / 12 
     between substr(age_compare_group, 0, instr(age_compare_group, '-') - 1) 
     and substr(age_compare_group, instr(age_compare_group, '-') + 1)
);
```

If, however, you really only want to compare with gender_compare and age_compare_group when both are given, and not to compare at all if only one or none of them are given (i.e. at least one of them is null), then do it like this:

```
select count(*)
  into user_count
from mstuser a
where 
( 
  (
    gender_compare is null 
   or 
    age_compare_group is null
  )
 or 
  (
    upper(a.gender) = upper(gender_compare)
   and
    months_between(sysdate, a.dob) / 12 
       between substr(age_compare_group, 0, instr(age_compare_group, '-') - 1) 
       and substr(age_compare_group, instr(age_compare_group, '-') + 1)
    )
);
```